# Traducción: Sorted vs. Ordered: Ordenado - Catalogado?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Repasando una serie de documentos y tutoriales me vino la pregunta de cómo traducir al español `sorted` y `ordered` para mantener la diferencia que ambos conceptos tienen en inglés. Aparte de `ordenado` no me venía ninguna otra palabra, y desde luego nada que matice la diferencia entre los dos conceptos.

Como sé que mucha gente ha llegado a este Stack a través de StackOverflow, me permitiré poner un ejemplo de programación (que es como me vino la duda). En cualquier caso, no creo que sea difícil de entender para aquellos no versados en programación.

El lenguaje de programación Java tiene un framework llamado *Collections* con diversas estructuras de datos que pueden ser útiles: Listas, Conjuntos, Diccionarios, etc.

Por ejemplo:

> A List is an **ordered** Collection (sometimes called a sequence)
>
> [Source: The List Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html)

Esto significa que la lista es una estructura ordenada. Si yo meto los números 35, 24 y 66 por ese orden, 35 es el primer elemento, 24 es el segundo y 66 el tercero.

Pero además,

> A SortedSet is a Set that maintains its elements in ascending order, **sorted** according to the elements' natural ordering or according to a Comparator provided at SortedSet creation time.
>
> [Source: The SortedSet Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-set.html)

Con lo que esta estructura también tiene un orden. El matiz es que la estructura me ordena los elementos según los inserto. Si inserto los mismos que he puesto antes en la lista, 24 sería el primer elemento, por se el más bajo, y 66 el último, por ser el más alto (24 < 35 < 66).

Con lo cual, también hay un orden, pero es distinto a lo que se entiende por orden en la lista.

He mirado algunos tutoriales en español, a ver si encontraba cómo se suele traducir esta diferencia entre `ordered` y `sorted`. Me vienen a la cabeza ciertos sinónimos para "ordenar" como catalogar, clasificar, organizar... Quizá diría que en una SortedSet los elementos están clasificados, pero nunca organizados o catalogados.

Hay una traducción para *ordered - sorted* que conserve este matiz?

Comment: @Gorpik tienes razón y pensé en esto, aunque crearía un cognado falso entre order y ordenar. Claro que en España el significado de arreglar (algo roto) puede hacer que una colección arreglada suene raro. Lo escogí más que nada por la acepción de sujetar a reglas, que así funcionan tal concepto en por ejemplo, SortedList en Java (si haces un nuevo comparador). Voy a pensarlo un poco más

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bueno, me parece un poco difícil encontrar algo ideal ya que en inglés esas dos palabras tienen efectivamente el mismo significado sobre todo en un contexto unidimensional como es un listado..

Primero, veamos las definiciones pertinentes:

> **ordered, *v.*** (OED)
>   **1.a.** To place in order, give order to; to arrange in a particular order; to arrange methodically or suitably.
>   **1.b.** To class; to rank. *Obs. rare.*
>
> **sort, *v.*** (OED)
>   **II.9.a.**  To arrange (things, etc.) according to kind or quality, or after some settled order or system; to separate and put into different sorts or classes; to classify; to assort
>   **II.10.a.** To place in a class or sort; to give a place to; to classify
>   **II.12.a.** *refl.* To form sets or groups by some process of combination or separation
>   **II.16.a.** To arrange or put in order; to put to rights in some respect

Efectivamente, son iguales.  Tal vez *sort* implique un poco más de atención a la categorización de las entidades.  A primera lectura, viénenme a la cabeza algunas palabras para *order*:

> **ordenar** (DRAE)
>   **1.** *tr.* Colocar de acuerdo con un plan o de modo conveniente.
>
> **colocar** (DRAE)
>   **1.** *tr.* Poner a alguien o algo en su debido lugar
>
> **secuenciar** (DRAE) 
>   **1.** *tr.* Establecer una secuencia (‖ serie o sucesión).

Y los para *sort*:

> **categorizar** (DRAE)
>   **1.** *tr.* Organizar o clasificar por categorías.
>
> **clasificar** (DRAE)
>   **1.** *tr.* Ordenar o disponer por clases.
>
> **organizar** (DRAE)
>   **2.** *tr.* Poner algo en orden.
>
> **disponer** (DRAE)
>   **1.** *tr.* Colocar, poner algo en orden y situación conveniente. *U. t. c. prnl.*
>
> **arreglar** (DRAE)
>   **1.** *tr.* Reducir o sujetar a regla; ajustar, conformar
>   **2.** *tr.* Componer, ordenar, concertar.
>
> **relacionar** (DRAE)
>   **2.** *tr.* Establecer relación entre personas, cosas, ideas o hechos. *U. t. c. prnl.*
>   **3.** *tr.* Hacer una lista de nombres o cosas
>
> **sortear** (DA - ASALE)
>   **I. 1.** *tr. EU.* Clasificar o poner *algo* en orden.

Casi todas tienen las mismas definiciones (y a las traducciones para *sort* podríamos añadir también palabras parecidas como *agrupar*, *apiñar*, incluso *discriminar*).  En muchos casos en inglés la elección de una u otra van por antojo del hablante, aunque como nativo, por lo general, diría que *order* es más bien de cosas homogéneas, y algo linear, mientras *sort* se suena más a organizar cosas heterogéneas y normalmente en grupos.

Por lo tanto, creo que si quisésemos mantener la distinción al máximo, podríamos decir ***ordenar*** y ***clasificar***.  Pero ya que hay más de un poco de traslapo dentro del entorno informático, yo opinaría que las mejores serían o **secuenciar** (*order*) y ***arreglar*** (*sort*), que mantendría el traslapo a la vez de encajar más con los usos informáticos (*secuenciar* da énfasis en la estructura serial sin señalar una ordenación, mientras *arreglar* suena más a una disposición bien pensada, aunque quizás tales connotaciones no sean panhispánicas).

Pero imagino que cualquier traducción de este tipo sería un poco *too late to the party*: seguramente los informáticos ya tienen sus traducciones sean adecuadas o no (ojalá no hubiesen repetido la estupidez de Microsoft con *font=fuente*)

Comment: Solo como PD: antes tenía *colocar* como la sugerencia para *order* (por ser como una agrupación pero con una connotación neutra — para mí al menos — con respeto a la disposición de los componentes), hasta que me acordé de *secuenciar*.

Comment: Me gusta *secuenciar* para *order*. De hecho, en informática este tipo de estructuras se llaman *secuencias* (en inglés, *sequence*). En cambio, *arreglar*, al menos en España, no me da el sentido que tiene la palabra *sort*; para esta no encuentro mejor traducción que *ordenar*.

Comment: @Gorpik tienes razón y pensé en esto, aunque crearía un cognado falso entre order y ordenar. Claro que en España el significado de arreglar (algo roto) puede hacer que una colección arreglada suene raro. Lo escogí más que nada por la acepción de sujetar a reglas, que así funcionan tal concepto en por ejemplo, SortedList en Java (si haces un nuevo comparador). Voy a pensarlo un poco más

Comment: Incluso en el caso de Java, *gestionar* serviría, traduciendo el concepto y no la palabra

Comment: Por un lado, *arreglar* me da la idea de un *arreglo*, palabra usada a veces para traducir *array*; sin embargo, un *array* es *ordered*, pero no *sorted*. En cuanto a *gestionar*, esa palabra se usa para traducir *manage*; así, *managed environment* es un *entorno gestionado*, que no tiene nada que ver con nuestro caso. Siento no dar opciones propias en lugar de solo encontrar problemas a las que ofreces tú, pero no se me ocurren.

Comment: Para que conste en acta, he buscado un libro de Java en español (castellano) y sólo usa _ordenado_. Eso sí, se hace la distinción de que tiene un _orden asociado_ a través de la interfaz _Comparable_. Por supuesto, para Quick**sort** o Merge**sort** tampoco ofrece traducción el libro. Muy buena respuesta (muy completa).